# Best way to collect unique objects

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I'm trying to collect only unique objects then output them to CSV file
is below code ok?! or is there a correct way to do that?

```
interface f {
    val s1: String
    val s2: String
    fun tot():Int
}

data class A(override val s1: String, override val s2:String, val sub_cost1: Int, val sub_cost2: Int) : f {
    override fun tot() : Int { return sub_cost1 + sub_cost2}
}
data class B(override val s1: String, override val s2:String, val b_cost: Int, val area: Int) : f {
    override fun tot() : Int { return b_cost}
}
data class C(override val s1: String, override val s2:String, val c_cost: Int) : f{
    override fun tot() : Int { return c_cost}
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val s = mutableSetOf<f>()
    s.add(C("a0","b0", 1))
    s.add(C("a0","b0", 1)) // equal to first elem, must not be added!
    s.add(A("a1","a2", 2, 3))
    s.add(B("b1","b2", 5, 6))

    // to output into CSV file
    println("s1, s2, sub_cost1, sub_cost2, b.cost, c.cost, tot")
    for (i in s) { 
        when (i) {
            is A -> println("${i.s1}, ${i.s2}, ${i.sub_cost1}, ${ i.sub_cost2}, , , ${i.tot()}")
            is B -> println("${i.s1}, ${i.s2}, , , ${i.b_cost}, , ${i.tot()}")
            is C -> println("${i.s1}, ${i.s2}, , , , ${i.c_cost}, ${i.tot()}")
        }
    }
}
```

expected output:

s1, s2, sub_cost1, sub_cost2, b_cost, c_cost, tot

a0, b0, , , , 1, 1

a1, a2, 2, 3, , , 5

b1, b2, , , 5, , 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's quite common to use a `Set` to automatically prevent duplicates.  I think it certainly counts as ‘correct’, and don't have anything obviously better to suggest here.

Note that this only works when the set can *tell* they're duplicates; so the objects need to have a suitable implementation of the `equals()` method, or you need to give the set a `Comparator` which does.  In this case, you're using `data class`es, which give you a suitable `equals()` implementation automatically.

Using a `Set` also makes your intentions clear to whoever's reading the code.

(Another advantage is that most implementations can check for the presence or absence of an object *very* quickly.  They have disadvantages, too: they tend to take more memory than a simple `List`, and the simpler implementations don't have a consistent or predictable iteration order.  But those aren't usually a problem — and if you need ordered iteration, you can use e.g. a `LinkedHashSet`.)

One thing I might look at changing in your code is the `when`; that requires the main part of the code to know about every implementation of `f`, and their internals.  The best approach isn't obvious.  If you think the string processing there is more tightly tied to the object internals than to the CSV format you're creating, you could instead add a method to your interface which returns a `String` (either the standard `toString()` method, or a method such as `toCSVLine()`); then each class can implement that as it sees fit, and the main code can just call that and not care about the details.  (Or if the CSV details are better kept together, then the `when` might be better after all.  Or you might find a hybrid approach, where method(s) in the `f` interface can provide all that's needed without needing to know anything about the implementation.)

(Also, I'd capitalise the `f` interface.  Kotlin (and Java) coding standards all start interface names with a capital letter, just like class names.)